# Catalog price rules - update on schedule

Tags: catalog-price-rules, magento2.4.2

I have updated my web shop to Magento 2.4.2 version and i would like to set my cron job to update every 48h just for Catalog price rules (catalogrule_rule). Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to overwrite the magento default cronjob schedule or you simply need the schedule expression for your own custom cronjob.

However, I will answer both with the code below: I think overwriting a core cronjob's schedule should be doable by creating a custom module and creating the `etc/crontab.xml` file that will overwrite the original one. The content should be the same, just a different schedule:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="catalogrule_apply_all" instance="Magento\CatalogRule\Cron\DailyCatalogUpdate" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 1 */2 * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

The `<schedule>0 1 */2 * *</schedule>` part will make the cronjob execute ***At 01:00 on every 2nd day-of-month.*** so you either use just this bit and adjust your own custom cronjob schedule or overwrite the core one, there you have it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and code sample. I will try to create my own module that overrides the cronjob schedule. My genuine problem is that i want to keep discounts for a longer period of time using the catalog price rule, but they automatically expire after 2 days. Do you know something about that?

Comment: that's weird.. unfortunately i didn't encounter this behavior in any of my projects, but isn't it maybe related to the expiration date of the rules?

Comment: I envy you if that is the case with your projects. I have 3 stores, and on each store every 2 days catalog price rules just vanish. Expiration dates are set for a year in advance so i don't think that is the problem.

Comment: yeah, that's probably not it then. hmmm, are you on EE? if so, are using content staging? i would probably look into that aaand also any other 3rd party module (disable them all on a test env and see if the issue still appears).